# I am trying to print numbers from 1 to 10 in sequential order with two different threads, but output is not always same

Tags: java, multithreading

This is how my code looks like, What is wrong with the code?
I want to print numbers in 1, 2,3,4,....10 but the output is 2,1,3,4,6...and it changes every time or is their any better way to implement this

```
class Th1 extends Thread{
    public void run (){
        try{
            for (int i=1; i<=10; i+=2){
            System.out.println ("VALUE OF ODD : "+i);
            Thread.sleep (1000);
            }
        }catch (InterruptedException ie){
            System.out.println (ie);
        }
    }
};
class Th2 implements Runnable{
    public void run (){
        try{
            for (int j=2; j<=10; j+=2){
                System.out.println ("VALUE OF EVEN : "+j);
                Thread.sleep (1000);
            }
        }catch (InterruptedException ie){
            System.out.println (ie);
        }
    }
};
class ThDemo6{
    public static void main (String [] args)    {
        Th1 t1=new Th1 ();// object of Thread class
        Th2 t2=new Th2 ();// object of Runnable class
        Thread t=new Thread (t2);// Runnable is converted into Thread object
        System.out.println ("BEFORE START T1 IS : "+t1.isAlive ());
        System.out.println ("BEFORE START T2 IS : "+t.isAlive ());
        t1.start ();
        t.start ();
        System.out.println ("AFTER START T1 IS : "+t1.isAlive ());
        System.out.println ("AFTER START T2 IS : "+t.isAlive ());
        try        {
            t1.join ();// to make thread to join together for getting performance
            t.join ();
        }        catch (InterruptedException ie)        {
            System.out.println (ie);
        }
        System.out.println ("AFTER JOINING T1 IS : "+t1.isAlive ());
        System.out.println ("AFTER JOINING T2 IS : "+t.isAlive ());
    }
}
```

Comment: We are not here to debug your code for you, so please post not your full code but a [mcve].

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html that might come in handy in multi-thread programs

Comment: You need a look that the two threads can share so only one can run at a time

Comment: The simplest solution is to use one thread. To use two threads you effectively need to ensure only one is ever running using locking.

Comment: I suggest only using Runnable wrapped with a Thread. I have never seen someone use both like this.

Comment: Why would you expect two separate thready – each scheduled by the OS separately – would consistently interleave their output? That is not how things work (and is a good thing): if you need threads to be synchronised then you need to do the synchronisation.

Comment: I wrote [this example](https://gist.github.com/RustyKnight/da90e83d95ce795c963ab3a4f942a19b) before it was closed, using `ReentrantLock`s and `Condition`s to control the output of the threads

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any control which thread gets CPU time first by the scheduler so the outputs will probably never be in your desired order.
Take a look at Javas thread model and CPU scheduling.

**EDIT**
Of course, you can use locks on variabels etc, but this would hurt the real concept of threads which is parallel tasks.
Maybe you should check if you have two parallel tasks. I think counting from 1 to X is one single task.

Comment: I am new to multi threading, can you tell me? Is their any way to take control of thread executions in Java?

Comment: There is no control, the operating system has a so called scheduler which operates at a defined strategy and only he can decide which thread or process will obtain the CPU next. If you use threads, you loose kind of control over your programm flow

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the code is it needs to produce sequential results, but you used threads to do that.